# How to select JAVA_HOME variable kali-linux

Tags: java, android-studio, environment-variables, kali-linux

Thank you very much in advance
I'm trying to use android studio to perform tests on kali linux but add the ambient variable `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`
in `.zshrc`
but when running studio.sh and in select SDK path it does not show the correct environment changeable pointing to `/home/$USER/android-studio/jre` and other `JAVA_HOME=/home/$USER/android-studio/jre`

how to show the ambient variable in Select default JDK Location

can it be how to perform?

my file `.zshrc`

```
...
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd4
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the folder only existed but the package was not yet installed,
then I ran the command.

- install package java-jdk8

  - `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

so it worked[image]